# Investigate Exception Object at runtime

Tags: .net, debugging, clr, heap-memory

I currently Need to debug a .net 3.5 application on the production System of the customer. Randomly the application is throwing strange interop.SEHExceptions. I would really like to take look at the .net objects in the Memory at the time of the Crash. For example i'd like to see the inner exception property of the exception or the errorCode property. What is the best Option to do so without installing visual studio (i'm not allowed to do so).
I'm a bit confused by multiple possibilities. I found Things like

- DbgClr
- Memory Dumps
- Intelli Trace
- Remote debugging

What is the easiest way to look at the objects in memory at the time of the Crash on a production machine?
thank you very much for your help

Comment: IIRC, support for dump debugging was introduced in CLRv4 and I don't think it would have been backported (WinDBG + SOS might sill work on a dump though). I believe IntelliTrace is a component of visual studio and not something you can use separately. I haven't used remote debugging but as far as i can tell, it would still require _some_ VS components to be installed (maybe the smaller subset is ok).

Comment: thank you for your answer. i think intellitrace can be used standalone: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh398365.aspx however i don't have pdb files for this Software so the only way i can go i think is with Kind of Memory dumps. so i don't really Need a Debugging/step-through i just Need to look at the objects in Memory at the time of the Crash. What is the best way to achieve it? how can i capture a dump where i can look at managed objects? :)

Comment: @LaurinSt ProcDump is the easiest option. You can have it generate a dump when the exception occurs. WinDbg is another option. No need to install; just copy the folder over to the target machine. Attach to the running process. Set it to break on the exception. Or you can stop on all managed exceptions (sxe clr). You can take a dump with .dump /ma <path>. Or if you want to debug live, load SOS (.loadby sos mscorwks) and use !sos.pe to print the last exception. Look at !sos.help for more commands.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a few questions, maybe you can help me:
As far as i understand i have several ways to create a dump file (procdump, windows does it, task manager, p/invokes, etc.). Ist there only one dump file format, is this format standardized? so can i analyze all these dump files with the same tools?
And what tools are there for analyzing these files? WinDbg and are there others? Can i load such a dump file in VS?
Thank you very much for giving me some hints. :)